# Is there a way to make a function available only in a function passed through argument in c++?

Tags: c++, function, lambda, error-handling, scope

I want to handle errors in my functions. I decided to do it with a callable argument into that function. So when a "user" is about to call that "dangerous" function he can specify an action to be done with e.g. lambda expression. I'd like that the user can call a certain function inside that lambda that is not accessible in the "users scope" (it may be accessible from some different hidden scope e.g. the same namespace as the dangerous function or even better namespace nested there) is there a way to do such a thing?

I might try to pass it as an argument to the lamda but that requires the user to know about that function. Even worse if id like to expose more than one function in that way.

Like so:

```cpp
#include "dangerous.hpp"
int main() {
   std::string error_description
   // call a function from dangerous.hpp
   dngr::doathing(
      "param1", "param2", "param3",
      [&error_description](int error_code){
         error_description = get_description(error_code);
         //                    ^
         // also provided by dangerous.hpp somehow
      }
   );


   return 0;
}
```

but the get_description() function nowhere to be seen (without looking around tooo much) definetley not in the default namespace

Comment: I suggest not asking people to use their imagination. Show some code that tries to do what you are saying.

Comment: sorry, edited the question

Comment: The example code you gave makes me wonder why you pass in an error code instead of an error object? An error object could come with member methods to get the code and to get the description. Could you give an example where adopting a simple object-oriented approach is inadequate?

Comment: as you said its just an example, but the idea behind was that i'd pass just the code (no extra data) and the description of the error would be hardcoded so no passing around unless error actually happens. I probably overthought it if i passed it by reference only pointer would be passed and the lifetime of the object passed would end after the execution of that lambda if it was created right before

Answer (score 1):

Passkey idiom might help:

First, create a structure with no public constructor, and make it a friend of one of your classes.

```cpp
class Key
{
private: // All private
    friend class MyClass; // only MyClass can use it.

    Key() {}

    Key(const Key&) = delete;
    Key& operator=(const Key&) = delete;
};
```

Now, declare your function to protect with that argument:

```cpp
void reset_password(const Key&, std::string);
std::string get_description(const Key&, int error_code);
```

Then, your class might ask for an appropriate functor:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
public:

    void doathing(
        std::string param1, std::string param2, std::string param3,
        std::function<void(const Key&, int)> func)
    {
        // ...
        auto error_code = 42;
        func({}, error_code);
    }
};
```

And in `main()`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    MyClass c;
    std::string error_description;
    c.doathing(
        "param1", "param2", "param3",
        [&error_description](const Key& key, int error_code){
            error_description = get_description(key, error_code);
        }
    );
    std::cout << error_description;
    // get_description({}, 42); // error: 'Key::Key()' is private within this context
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ebc60434cf0d834)

Comment: That wouldn't work for me. My goal was just to conveniently insert the function into the lambda without messing with the default or dngr namespace. But i really appreciate your approach it is quite interesting. I voted your answer up but i don't have enough rep yet for it to be seen.